# How do I keep a ClickHandler from being called twice on a button in GWT?

Tags: gwt, button, dialog, click

Here's the setup: I have a page, we'll call it A, which contains a button, we'll call it B. When a user clicks on B, a dialog opens (C). C knows nothing about A or B once it has been created.

Right now, if a user double-clicks on B, 2 or more Cs are created, which is not desirable. Since C knows nothing about B, I cannot disable the button because if a user presses Cancel in C, they will go back to A but B will still be disabled. I also can't save the page ID and limit C from being created that way because if a user does open C, clicks Cancel but then decides to open C again, they have to be able to do that.

How can I stop the button from allowing more than one dialog to open, no matter how many clicks are done in succession?

**EDIT**
I simplified too much in the above description, so here's a more in depth look. My `Toolbar` class has a button called `reference`. When `reference` is clicked, a function is called on an entirely separate class, `ItemPicker`, which creates and displays the `CreateConversation` dialog. So, relating back to my original scenario, B doesn't know anything about C. I realize this is convoluted, but it's not something I can change at the moment.

Somehow, I need to stop `reference` from making a second call to `ItemPicker.createAndShow()` if it's clicked more than once and a `CreateConversation` dialog is already being opened. Also, there isn't a specific instance of `ItemPicker` in the `Toolbar` class; `createAndShow()` is a static method.

Comment: In the interest of not editing too much for a simple addition: A also doesn't have a specific reference to C. That's sort of implied by my description of their relationship, but I'd rather be explicit and avoid confusion.

Comment: I have not forgotten this question. A lot has happened the last couple weeks. I will test the most recent suggestion, by @Thomas Broyer, in the morning (US Mountain Time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C doesn't know B, but B knows C: keep a handle on it and call `show()`. If C is already displayed, it will be a no-op, if has been closed (or not yet opened), it will show up.

Comment: This is no different: keep a handle on your `CreateConversation` dialog in a static field of `ItemPicker`.

Comment: Saving a view in the ItemPicker and checking to see if it's null did the trick! Well, I also had to remove the view from its parent and the parent from _its_ parent so that it would work, but you answered my question! :)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably A has a reference to C.

When *Cancel* is clicked in C, call `C.hide()`. Now in your `ClickHandler` for B you can check `C.isShowing()` and enable/disable creating a dialog, or re-displaying the same dialog using `C.show()`.

When *Cancel* is clicked in C, in addition to calling `hide()` you can re-initialize C and keep it around for the next B click.

Comment: A does not have a reference to C. See my edit and added comment.